# android get value for the spinner choose by user

Tags: android, android-spinner

i am developing an android application. here is what i want.

there is gender spinner;male and female. when the user choose male, it will appear image1, but when choose female, the image1 disappear. i am thinking of using set.alpha(0).

here is my code.

```
public class Froyo2Activity extends Activity {
    Spinner genderSpin;
    ImageView image1;
    Button submit;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_froyo2);

        addButtonListener();
    }

    public void addButtonListener(){
        submit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.submit);
        image1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        genderSpin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.gender_spin);

        submit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){            
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {                
                if(genderSpin.getSelectedItemPosition() == 1){
                    image1.setAlpha(0);
                }
            }
        });     
    }
}
```

this is my code froyo2.xml in res/layout

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/widget54"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="819dp"
    tools:context=".RelativeActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Welcome"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="131dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Priority Level"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout1" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/prior_spin"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:entries="@array/priorArray"
            android:prompt="@string/prior_prompt" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout2" >

    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Age"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:text="5.1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Select ETA" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:text="BP/P"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView9"
        android:text="ETA"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Location"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText6"
        android:text="Submit 5.1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText4"
        android:text="Special Handling"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Drug"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView10"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:text="Firstname"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView4"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="Lastname"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:text="OriFroyoAge" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Diagnostic"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/back2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView10"
        android:src="@drawable/malefull" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="124dp"
        android:text="Injury(s)"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Gender"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/gender_spin"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
        android:entries="@array/genderArray"
        android:prompt="@string/gender_prompt" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and this one is in res/layout-land

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/widget54"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="798dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".RelativeActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Welcome"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Priority Level"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/spinner2"
        android:entries="@array/priorArray"
        android:prompt="@string/prior_prompt" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView7"
        android:entries="@array/genderArray"
        android:prompt="@string/gender_prompt" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner1"
        android:text="Firstname"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="Lastname"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
        android:text="Age"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView6"
        android:text="Age" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="BP/P" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
        android:text="ETA" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView4"
        android:text="BP/P"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:text="ETA"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
        android:src="@drawable/malefull" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:text="Gender"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Location"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
        android:text="Special Handling"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView10"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
        android:text="Drug(s)"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
        android:text="Diagnostic"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView12"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText6"
        android:text="Submit" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/back2" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

then i run it in the emulator and when click the button submit it said force the application closed. i have making the breakpoints and i think `genderSpin.getSelectedItemPosition()` is the cause. but how can i have the value that user choose for the spinner?

your help is appreciate.

===EDIT FOR SOLUTION.STATUS CLOSED===

thank you for those who helped me a lot with this. this is my final solution. i need to make SpinnerAdapter first to retrieved the context of the spinner selected.

i also followed tutorial from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)

my last code would be

```
genderSpin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.gender_spin);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.genderArray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    genderSpin.setAdapter(adapter);
    genderSpin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos, long arg3){
            String fontname = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
            Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "The External Font Is " +fontname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

after selected spinner item, it will toast out "The External Font Is Female" if choosing female and toast out "The External Font Is Male" if choosing male. Thank you for the helped. Hope this could be good guidance for those who seeking for the help.

Comment: Can you post the associated xml file (activity_froyo2.xml) ?

Comment: @Dalmas i include together with my layout.hope it could help

Comment: @sarabrown post error logcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can u please post your spinner OnItemSelectedListener code. In the button onclick only you are added the code for getting spinner position. Below code i am used for getting the user choosed spinner item.

```
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);
    private OnItemSelectedListener listener =new OnItemSelectedListener() {
      //do what ever you want to do when item selected


    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos,
            long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        fontname=parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
         Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "The External Font Is " +fontname, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
       }
```

Comment: Thank you @Nathiya. it works. i really appreciate your helped. i also edit my post to the solution i made referring yours. hope it could give good guidance for those seeking for help.